# String regex: Remove square brackets from part of the string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

In JavaScript application I need to edit string.

Text comes with this structure:

- It may start with a prefix in square brackets **[prefix]**. I need to keep this prefix with brackets.
- Second comes [whatever string], but this time I only need to keep string within brackets

**Example 1:**

> [prefix][My title]
>
> Returns: [prefix] My title

**Example 2**

> [Another title without prefix]
>
> Returns: Another title without prefix

Comment: Is it mandatory to use regex?

Comment: It's not. I did some operations such as slice, substr, concat, but was wondering that regex may look more elegant.

Comment: Look for "`][`". If found - remove '`[`' from the pair and `']'` from the end.

Answer (score -1):

This will help you identify any text that is inside brackets

`const keyRegex = /(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])/gmdi`

With this try to use Regex.exec() from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).
Following the example from Mozilla developers you could check if array1[0] is equal with prefix or not.
Happy coding

Usually more "elegant" code is hard to understand even by future you (can't use comments yet )